# Rust on Bathroom Radiator (Towel Rail)

Tags: bathroom, radiator, rust

I've a 36 Month old Bathroom Radiator (towel rail) that is connected to the central heating system and has started 'growing' rust (see pictures).
Is there any method to remove the rust & stop this from happening again or will I need to purchase a new radiator ?
Model: https://www.screwfix.com/p/blyss-towel-radiator-1200-x-600mm-white-2101btu/9560v

[image: Towel rail with rust spots]
[image: Close-up of rust spots]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is but I doubt you will like the answer:

1. Strip the existing paint off of this thing.
2. Remove all the rust down to clean metal.
3. Refinish this properly so that it doesn't rust again.

Anything else you try that does not remove the rust that has already started will fail as the rust will eventually push any coating off and continue rusting.

I notice that in the URL you linked, the text says there is a 5 year warranty.  You may want to contact the manufacturer about a claim.

Comment: Definitely go for the warranty. As jwh20 says, once penetrated, rust will propagate below the paint layer so it would otherwise be a never ending story.

Comment: Want to bet that the "T&C's apply" includes a stipulation to not hang damp towels on it?

Comment: @SiHa LOL!  But you are probably correct.

Comment: If not covered by warrantee , I would just paint it because as @ jwh20  points out , a good job is a lot of work.